# salesforce: jquery file upload within apex:tabpanel

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to set up jquery file upload in apex page.(http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) so I can upload multiple images at the same time to s3. It works perfectly on chrome/firefox/IE9 but I have problem submitting in IE10. The problem onlyl occurs if I put this plugin with apex:tabpanel it doesn't matter if the form is within the tabpanel or outside of tabpanel it just doesn't submit if the tabpanel exists within the same page. If i debug through xhr throws error saying "access is denied". I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

$j.support.cross = true;
$j('#fileupload').fileupload({
   url: myurl
})

Comment: After the research and digging into the code, I noticed whenever you new the XMLHttpRequest salesforce ajax tool is creating activex object in IE I am not sure if this is bug on Salesforce. I need to create XMLHttpRequest in order to upload images to S3 using cros

Answer (score 0):

For IE 10, Salesforce ajax tool hijacks the XMLHttpResponse without checking if the IE supports XHR that's why it was not able to upload files with jquery file uploader.( being hijacked XMLHttpResponse turned into old ActiveXObject. Here is the why it was hijacked.

```
XMLHttpRequest=function(){
  if(!_SARISSA_XMLHTTP_PROGID){_SARISSA_XMLHTTP_PROGID=Sarissa.pickRecentProgID(["Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP","Microsoft.XMLHTTP"]);}
```

So I had to get it back the original XMLHttpRequest it was saved on Sarissa object. The good thing is the original request was saved on sarrissa object. However I am not sure why they need to do this.

```
$j.ajaxSetup({
  xhr: function() {
    var req;
    req = Sarissa.originalXMLHttpRequest();
    return req;
  }
});
```